# Setting ReadOnly attribute to all Textboxes in Array of Controls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have the following code looping through a variety of arrayed controls in a form:

```
For r As Long = LBound(ctrlArray) To UBound(ctrlArray)
        If TypeOf ctrlArray(r) Is TextBox Then
            ctrlArray(r).Text = ""

            If ctrlArray(r).ReadOnly = False Then
                ctrlArray(r).ReadOnly = True
            End If
        Else
            If ctrlArray(r).Enabled = True Then
                ctrlArray(r).Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

I receive the error "'ReadOnly' is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Control" when trying to set textboxes as read only.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this right before I hit the submit button. Thought I would share anyway:

```
Dim tbx As TextBox
For r As Long = LBound(ctrlArray) To UBound(ctrlArray)
     If TypeOf ctrlArray(r) Is TextBox Then
          ctrlArray(r).Text = ""
          tbx = ctrlArray(r)
          If tbx.ReadOnly = False Then
               tbx.ReadOnly = True
          End If
     Else
         If ctrlArray(r).Enabled = True Then
               ctrlArray(r).Enabled = False
         End If
     End If
Next
```

Comment: I think DirectCast may have also worked as well although not tested

Comment: That's basically what he does by using `tbx = ctrlArray(r)`. It's just implicit.

Comment: @Jens I know, all of it is written by me :P (was just adding for clarity/other options)